# Al insertar datos en una tabla me inserta otra y me da duplicado C# EF 6 Code First

Tags: c#, entity-framework

en esta oportunidad los molesto para ver si me pueden ayudar.
Estoy haciendo un desarrollo en C# Entitiy framework 6 Code First, tengo un modelo Empresa y otro Sobre,
donde una empresa puede tener muchos sobres. Lo que me pasa es que al querer insertar un sobre obtengo un error que no se pueden insertar elementos duplicados en la tabla Empresa cuando lo que yo estoy haciendo es insertar un sobre. Les dejo el código a ver si me pueen ayudar.

Modelo Sobre

```
public class Sobre
{
    public long id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string fechaEmision { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Empresa empresa { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Index(IsUnique = true)]
    public long numeroSobre { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string nombreArchivo { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public bool enviadoDGI { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string fechaEnviadoDGI { get; set; }
    public string respuestaDGI { get; set; }
    public byte[] archivo { get; set; }
}
```

Modelo empresa

```
public class Empresa
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string NombreComercial { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(12)]
    [Index(IsUnique = true)]
    public string Rut { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string RazonSocial { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string Telefono { get; set; }
    public string ResolucionIva { get; set; }
    public List<Sucursal> Sucursales { get; set; }
    public List<Sobre> sobres { get; set; }
}
```

Inserción

```
file = null;
                sobre1.archivo = file;
                datosEmpresa datosEmpresa = new datosEmpresa();
                Empresa empresa = new Empresa();
                oReply reply1 = new oReply();
                reply1 = datosEmpresa.BuscarEmpresaPorRut("2123132123131");

                empresa = (Empresa)reply1.Data;
                sobre1.empresa =empresa;
                sobre1.enviadoDGI = false;


                sobre1.fechaEmision = DateTime.Now.ToString();
                sobre1.nombreArchivo = "fefefefefgafheagfh";
                sobre1.numeroSobre = 27;
                sobre1.respuestaDGI = "mal";
                



                db.Sobres.Add(sobre1);
                db.SaveChanges();
```

Exception

An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.

InnerException = {"No se puede insertar una fila de clave duplicada en el objeto 'dbo.Empresas' con índice único 'IX_Rut'. El valor de la clave duplicada es (2123132123131).\r\nSe terminó la instrucción."}

Les agradezco si me pueden dar una mano ya que estoy trancado
Graciaaaaaaaasssssssss

Comment: Le has puesto la restricción aquí: `[Index(IsUnique = true)]` en `public string Rut { get; set; }` ¿Has insertado antes esa data?

Comment: Eso está bien ya que no deben haber dos rut duplicados, pero de todas maneras me hace una inserción de empresa cuando lo que estoy mandando a insertar en un sobre

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Después de mucho, mucho trabajo, encontré el problema. Cuando realizo las búsquedas

```
Empresa empresa = datosEmpresa.Buscar("216605580013");
ConfigSys configSys = datosConfiguracion.Buscar(1);
```

, estas deben ser hechas en la misma clase y función donde estoy grabando el objeto sucursal, todavía no logro entender porqué pero ese es el problema. Dejo el Código correcto.

```
public static void Guardar(Sucursal sucursal, string empresaRut, long idConfig)
{
using (DBModel DB = new DBModel())
{
Empresa empresa = (from e in DB.Empresas
where e.Rut == empresaRut
select e).FirstOrDefault();
ConfigSys configSys = (from e in DB.ConfigSys
where e.Id == idConfig
select e).FirstOrDefault();
sucursal.ConfigSys = configSys;
sucursal.Empresa = empresa;
sucursal.ConfigSys = configSys;
sucursal.Empresa = empresa;
DB.Sucursales.Add(sucursal);
DB.SaveChanges();
}
}
```

Gracias a todos los que intentaron ayudarme

Answer (score 0):

Tal vez en tu clase Sobre en lugar de tener un dato del tipo Empresa debieras tener un IdEmpresa ya que la Empresa la tienes creada en otra tabla. Basándonos sen esto:

Yo cambiaría:

```
[Required]
// public Empresa empresa { get; set; }
public long IdEmpresa {get; set;}
```

Y luego en la porción de código:

```
 empresa = (Empresa)reply1.Data;
 // sobre1.empresa =empresa;
 sobre1.IdEmpresa = empresa.Id;
 sobre1.enviadoDGI = false;
```

Comment: Lo que pasa que estaría rompiendo la relación y por ende luego no podría obtener las consultas completas

Comment: Precisamente esa es la relación IdEmpresa que evita que guardes una Empresa ya existente cada vez de guardas un Sobre.

Answer (score 0):

a ver según tus models y lo que planteas el modelo de empresa esta bien, porque solo debe existir una vez, la relación de empresa-sobre, la cuestión es ver como guardar la entidad sobre porque debes pasarle el id de la empresa a la que pertenece la empresa en la view donde registrar el sobre debes pasar el id de la empresa, seria bueno ver el codigo de la view donde insertar el sobre pero a simple vista.

intenta poner en la view de create sobre el siguiente código

```
 @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
 @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
```

se supone que estos datos tiene que venir del controller en su metodo get